# How to play a movie fullscreen using MPMoviePlayerViewController on a view that is being called modally

Tags: objective-c, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

In a view I have this code to play a movie fullscreen:

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stream.qtv.apple.com/events/jan/1201oihbafvpihboijhpihbasdouhbasv/12pibasvpqihbsdfvihbasdv01_iphone_vod_ref.mov"];

self.mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
NSLog(@"self mpc: %@", self.mpc);
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)  
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                           object:self.mpc ];
self.mpc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
self.mpc.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES; 
self.mpc.view.frame = self.view.frame;

[self.view addSubview:self.mpc.view];
self.mpc.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
[self.mpc.moviePlayer play];
```

The view itself is being called with this code

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
 bundle: nil];
 TestViewController *controller = [mainStoryboard 
 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"testController"];
 [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

The movie is playing ok, but on the top there is some room the MPMoviePlayerViewController isn't using.

Here's a screenshot showing the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dje2ar6ynk6855/IMG_2447.PNG

(I've made the background of the testController view yellow)

How can this movie be played fullscreen?

Comment: There is a dedicated version of -presentModalViewController for Movie Players... I don't remember the exact name right now, but it should come up in auto completion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y-100);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

If that doesn't work, try not using a modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to present the video in another modal, something like:

I didn't test this code, but I think it can solve your problem, because probably the problem that you are presenting is because of the previous modal.

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stream.qtv.apple.com/events/jan/1201oihbafvpihboijhpihbasdouhbasv/12pibasvpqihbsdfvihbasdv01_iphone_vod_ref.mov"];

self.mpc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
NSLog(@"self mpc: %@", self.mpc);
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)  
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                           object:self.mpc ];
self.mpc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
self.mpc.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES; 
self.mpc.view.frame = self.view.frame;

[self presentModalViewController:self.mpc animated:NO];
self.mpc.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
[self.mpc.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: The problem with that approach (which I used before) is that when the application is playing a movie, and then goes in the background, when the app resumes the movie isn't playing or visible anymore.

Comment: Have you tried the presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated: method ? In my last projects I am not using MPMoviePlayer :/

Comment: presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated works, but when the app resumes after resign, the movie isn't playing and isn't visible anymore...

Comment: To this problem, I will use AVPlayer, it is the best option for me when you need a not default feature from MPMoviePlayer.